# HTML formatting error

Tags: html, css

Basically the goal is to have 2 main sections in between this code. 1 Section to the left which is all text and the other which is to the right which on top is the table of properties then underneath the table images.

```css
@font-face { font-family: UbuntuG; src: url('ubuntu-fonts/Ubuntu-L.ttf'); } 
body {
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}
h1 {
    color: white; font-family: UbuntuG; font-size: 30;
}
h2 {
    color: white; font-family: UbuntuG; font-size: 18;
}
p {
    color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16;
}
p_ANum {
    color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 10; text-align: left;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #1d1d1d; border-spacing: 0; color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16; 
}
td  {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    height: 48px;
    min-width:48px;
}
ul{
  margin: 0px 0;
}
a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      height:43px;
      line-height:43px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Periodic Table</title>
    <meta content="??">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
    <style>
        table, th, td { border: 5px solid white; border-spacing: 0; color: #1d1d1d; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="margin-top:20;margin-left:15%;margin-right:3%;">
    <h1>Hydrogen</h1>
    
    <div align="right">
      <table><tr><h2>Atomic Properties</h2>
          <td bgcolor=white><b>Atomic number</b></td>
          <td bgcolor=white>1</td>
      </tr><tr>
          <td bgcolor=white><b>Atomic Mass</b></td>
          <td bgcolor=white>1.007825 g.mol ^-1</td>
      </tr><tr>
          <td bgcolor=white><b>Electronegativity</b></td>
          <td bgcolor=white>2.1</td>
      </tr><tr>
          <td bgcolor=white><b>Densitys</b></td>
          <td bgcolor=white>0.0899*10 ^-3 g.cm ^-3 at 20 °C</td>
      </tr><tr>
          <td bgcolor=white><b>Melting Point</b></td>
          <td bgcolor=white>- 259.2 °C</td>
      </tr><tr>
          <td bgcolor=white><b>Boiling Point</b></td>
          <td bgcolor=white>- 252.8 °C</td>
      </tr><tr>
          <td bgcolor=white><b>Vanderwaals radius</b></td>
          <td bgcolor=white>0.12 nm</td>
      </tr><tr>
          <td bgcolor=white><b>Ionic Radius</b></td>
          <td bgcolor=white>0.208 (-1) nm</td>
      </tr><tr>
          <td bgcolor=white><b>Isotopes</b></td>
          <td bgcolor=white>3</td>
      </tr><tr>
          <td bgcolor=white><b>Electronic shell</b></td>
          <td bgcolor=white>1s^1</td>
      </tr><tr>
          <td bgcolor=white><b>Energy of first Ionisation</b></td>
          <td bgcolor=white>1311 kJ.mol -1</td>
      </tr><tr>
          <td bgcolor=white><b>Discovered by</b></td>
          <td bgcolor=white>Henry Cavendish 1766</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
        <div align="Right">
        <img src="assets/H_atomic.png">
        <img src="assets/H_mainpic.png"> 
    </div>
    <span align="left">
        <p>
First element in the periodic table. In normal conditions it’s a colourless, odourless and insipid gas, formed by diatomic molecules, H2. The hydrogen atom, symbol H, is formed by a nucleus with one unit of positive charge and one electron. Its atomic number is 1 and its atomic weight 1,00797 g/mol. It’s one of the main compounds of water and of all organic matter, and it’s widely spread not only in The Earth but also in the entire Universe. There are three hydrogen isotopes: protium, mass 1, found in more than 99,985% of the natural element; deuterium, mass 2, found in nature in 0.015% approximately, and tritium, mass 3, which appears in small quantities in nature, but can be artificially produced by various nuclear reactions.

Uses: The most important use of hydrogen is the ammonia synthesis. The use of hydrogen is extending quickly in fuel refinement, like the breaking down by hydrogen (hydrocracking), and in sulphur elimination. Huge quantities of hydrogen are consumed in the catalytic hydrogenation of unsaturated vegetable oils to obtain solid fat. Hydrogenation is used in the manufacture of organic chemical products. Huge quantities of hydrogen are used as rocket fuels, in combination with oxygen or fluor, and as a rocket propellent propelled by nuclear energy. 
Hydrogen can be burned in internal combustion engines. Hydrogen fuel cells are being looked into as a way to provide power and research is being conducted on hydrogen as a possible major future fuel. For instance it can be converted to and from electricity from bio-fuels, from and into natural gas and diesel fuel, theoretically with no emissions of either CO2 or toxic chemicals.

Properties: Common hydrogen has a molecular weight of 2,01594 g. As a gas it has a density of 0.071 g/l at 0ºC and 1 atm. Its relative density, compared with that of the air, is 0.0695. Hydrogen is the most flammable of all the known substances. Hydrogen is slightly more soluble in organic solvents than in water. Many metals absorb hydrogen. Hydrogen absorption by steel can result in brittle steel, which leads to fails in the chemical process equipment.

At normal temperature hydrogen is a not very reactive substance, unless it has been activated somehow; for instance, by an appropriate catalyser. At high temperatures it’s highly reactive.

Although in general it’s diatomic, molecular hydrogen dissociates into free atoms at high temperatures. Atomic hydrogen is a powerful reductive agent, even at ambient temperature. It reacts with the oxides and chlorides of many metals, like silver, copper, lead, bismuth and mercury, to produce free metals. It reduces some salts to their metallic state, like nitrates, nitrites and sodium and potassium cyanide. It reacts with a number of elements, metals and non-metals, to produce hydrides, like NAH, KH, H2S and PH3. Atomic hydrogen produces hydrogen peroxide, H2O2, with oxygen.

Atomic hydrogen reacts with organic compounds to form a complex mixture of products; with etilene, C2H4, for instance, the products are ethane, C2H6, and butane, C4H10. The heat released when the hydrogen atoms recombine to form the hydrogen molecules is used to obtain high temperatures in atomic hydrogen welding.

Hydrogen reacts with oxygen to form water and this reaction is extraordinarily slow at ambient temperature; but if it’s accelerated by a catalyser, like platinum, or an electric spark, it’s made with explosive violence.
        </p>
    </span>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd look at using `th` for your row headers. Also note that `bgcolor` is non standard (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) and you should use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you don't use either IDs or classes on the elements that you want to display next to each other. This makes it very hard for your CSS to target. I'll fix that in the fiddle provided, by adding classes `.left` and `.right`.

The next problem is that you forgot to close your `<table>` tag. I've fixed that in the fiddle provided.

The third problem is that you have both a `background-color` and `color` of `white` for your table cells, making them very hard to read. You didn't initially notice this, because of your missing end tag for the table (which meant that the styles were not applied to it). You can fix that up by changing either the background-color or color to black:

```
td {
    color: #000;
}
```

The fourth problem is that you really want to move your images so that they're contained within the same container as the table, so that the floats work as expected...

Instead of:

```
    </tr>
</div>
    <div align="Right">
    <img src="assets/H_atomic.png">
    <img src="assets/H_mainpic.png"> 
</div>
```

Simply use:

```
    </tr>
    <img src="assets/H_atomic.png">
    <img src="assets/H_mainpic.png"> 
</div>
```

I've fixed this up in my fiddle.

Now that the code is fixed up, in order to make the components display like you want, you need to give them a width, and float them to the left, as such:

```
.left, .right {
    float: right;
    width: 46%;
    padding: 2%;
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/dx8sz1yn/) for a working example.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you it certainly helped me out a lot.  However if I want to separate the page into 3 equal categories with images going on the far left, text going in the center, and the same table of value on the very right how would I do that?

Comment: You would require three columns, each with a width of 33.33% (minus margins). You may wish to look into Bootstrap in that regard :) However, that's not your original question, and should warrant a new question to be asked :)

Comment: Please don't use `h2` as a child of `tr` as it is invalid html.

Comment: @JonP -- It was like that in the original HTML. Well spotted though, as that slipped by me.